# PySpark error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have timestamp dataset which is in format of

And I have written a udf in pyspark to process this dataset and return as Map of key values. But am getting below error message.

Dataset:df_ts_list

```
+--------------------+
|             ts_list|
+--------------------+
|[1477411200, 1477...|
|[1477238400, 1477...|
|[1477022400, 1477...|
|[1477224000, 1477...|
|[1477256400, 1477...|
|[1477346400, 1476...|
|[1476986400, 1477...|
|[1477321200, 1477...|
|[1477306800, 1477...|
|[1477062000, 1477...|
|[1477249200, 1477...|
|[1477040400, 1477...|
|[1477090800, 1477...|
+--------------------+
```

Pyspark UDF:

```
>>> def on_time(ts_list):
...     import sys
...     import os
...     sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
...     os.system("sudo apt-get install python-numpy -y")
...     import numpy as np
...     import datetime
...     import time
...     from datetime import timedelta
...     ts = np.array(ts_list)
...     if ts.size == 0:
...             count = 0
...             duration = 0
...             st = time.mktime(datetime.now())
...             ymd = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(st).date())
...     else:
...             ts.sort()
...             one_tag = []
...             start = float(ts[0])
...             for i in range(len(ts)):
...                     if i == (len(ts)) - 1:
...                             end = float(ts[i])
...                             a_round = [start, end]
...                             one_tag.append(a_round)
...                     else:
...                             diff = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts[i+1])) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts[i])))
...                             if abs(diff.total_seconds()) > 3600:
...                                     end = float(ts[i])
...                                     a_round = [start, end]
...                                     one_tag.append(a_round)
...                                     start = float(ts[i+1])
...             one_tag = [u for u in one_tag if u[1] - u[0] > 300]
...             count = int(len(one_tag))
...             duration = int(np.diff(one_tag).sum())
...             ymd = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).date())
...     return {'count':count,'duration':duration, 'ymd':ymd}
```

Pyspark code:

```
>>> on_time=udf(on_time, MapType(StringType(),StringType()))
>>> df_ts_list.withColumn("one_tag", on_time("ts_list")).select("one_tag").show()
```

Error:

> ```
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
>     process()
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
>     serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
>     func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 92, in <lambda>
>     mapper = lambda a: udf(*a)
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
>     return lambda *a: f(*a)
>   File "<stdin>", line 27, in on_time
>   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 39, in _
>     jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
> ```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 73):

Mariusz answer didn't really help me. So if you like me found this because it's the only result on google and you're new to pyspark (and spark in general), here's what worked for me.

In my case I was getting that error because I was trying to execute pyspark code before the pyspark environment had been set up.

Making sure that pyspark was available and set up before doing calls dependent on `pyspark.sql.functions` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: as an additional for others... i hit this error when my spark session had not been set up and I had defined a pyspark UDF using a decorator to add the schema. I normally set up spark session in my main, but in this case, when passing a complex schema needed to set it up at the top of script. thanks for the quick hint!

Comment: To add on to this, I got this error when using a spark function in a default value for a function, since those are evaluated at import time, not call-time. E.g. `def func(is_test = lit(False))`

Comment: Or, for others as stupid as me, you can encounter this error if you write pyspark code inside a `pandas_udf` (which is supposed to receive pandas code...)

Comment: Hi @JacksonHaenchen, can you please share how did you solve this? I have the similar situation i believe; I use from `pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col` and 
`var_is_not_empty = (col('var') != lit(''))` which is later used in the `filter' task within a function (A) in .py file (File1). This function(A) is then called from another .py file(File2). Wondering whats going wrong still. Thanks

Comment: @Mari all I can advise is that you cannot use pyspark functions before the spark context is initialized. In my case I was using them as a default arg value, but those are evaluated at import time, not runtime, so the spark context is not initialized. So I just changed it to None and checked inside the function.

Comment: @Mari I ran into this recently. If you want to take this construction, instead of assigning it as a variable, return it via a function. E.g. `def is_not_empty(): return (col('var') != lit(''))`. Then use it as a function instead of a variable. This allows it to be instantiated when called (after spark context is initialized) rather than when the module is loaded.

Comment: Thanks@Brendan, this helped. Appreciate the details.

Comment: Thanks@JacksonHaenchen for the details.

Comment: Thanks @RicS you saved me quite some time!

Comment: To be perfectly clear - to overcome this, one needs to instantiate the SparkSession object as early as possible. Not as in the first directive under `if __name__ == "__main__"` that comes at the end of the script, but above all code that is going to use PySpark.

Answer (score 25):

The error message says that in 27th line of udf you are calling some pyspark sql functions. It is line with `abs()` so I suppose that somewhere above you call `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` and it overrides python's `abs()` function.

Comment: Is there a way to use the original `abs()` function without deleting the line `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` ?

Comment: @mufmuf sure, you can use `__builtin__.abs` as a pointer to python's function

Comment: or you can import pyspark.sql.functions as F and use F.function_name to call pyspark functions

Comment: Thank you so much, instead of  `abs`, I had `round`.

Comment: I used `math.fabs()` instead

Comment: such a weird message for such an error. totally misleading. I wonder what is the path that ends up leading to a _jvm attribute related error

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI All pyspark code is evaluated by py4j. It's all transpiled to JVM calls

Answer (score 12):

Just to be clear the problem a lot of guys are having is stemming from a single bad programming style. That is `from blah import *`

When you guys do

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

you overwrite ***a lot*** of python builtins functions. I strongly recommending importing functions like

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
# or 
import pyspark.sql.functions as pyf
```

Comment: This advice helped me correct my bad habit of using '*' when importing. Hope others would correct this too

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are initializing the Spark context. For example:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("...") \
    .getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
productData = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").load()
```

Or as in

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('company').getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
productData = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ",") \
    .option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"") \
    .option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("/path/thecsv.csv")
```

Comment: You can use the SparkSession to get a Dataframe reader. Don't need the sql context

Answer (score 4):

This exception also arises when the `udf` can not handle `None` values.
For example the following code results in the same exception:

```
get_datetime = udf(lambda ts: to_timestamp(ts), DateType())
df = df.withColumn("datetime", get_datetime("ts"))
```

However this one does not:

```
get_datetime = udf(lambda ts: to_timestamp(ts) if ts is not None else None, DateType())
df = df.withColumn("datetime", get_datetime("ts"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this error in my jupyter notebook. I added the below commands

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="<add-your-name-here>")
```

and it worked.

its the same problem of `spark context not ready or Stopped`

Comment: You should be using a SparkSession, though. You can get the context from that, if needed

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, when I had python's `round()` function in my code and like @Mariusz said *python's `round()` function got overridden*.

The workaround for this was to use `__builtin__.round()` instead of `round()` like @Mariusz mentions in the comments in his answer.

Comment: Or you rename whatever other round function you've defined/imported

Answer (score 0):

In all probability, this error occurs due to absence of spark session creation. So, spark session should be created.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder
       .master('yarn')
       .appName('a').getOrCreate()
```

This should resolve.