# How to add a column to a pyspark dataframe which contains the mean of one based on the grouping on another column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aggregate, mean

It is similar to some other questions but it is different.

Let say we have a pyspark dataframe df as below:

```
+-----+------+-----+        
|col1 | col2 | col3| 
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  6  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   6  |  3  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  9  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   9  |  6  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   3  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   9  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|C    |  3   |  4  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|C    |  5   |  1  |
+-----+------+-----+
```

I want to add another column as new_col which contains the mean of col2 based on grouping on col1. So, the answer must be as follows

```
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |col1 | col2 | col3 | new_col|
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  6   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  8   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   6  |  3   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  9   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  B  |   9  |  6   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  B  |   3  |  8   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+    
   |  B  |   9  |  8   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  C  |   3  |  4   | 4      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  C  |   5  |  1   | 4      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Creating the DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
values = [('A',5,6),('A',5,8),('A',6,3),('A',5,9),('B',9,6),('B',3,8),('B',9,8),('C',3,4),('C',5,1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['col1','col2','col3'])
df.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   A|   5|   6|
|   A|   5|   8|
|   A|   6|   3|
|   A|   5|   9|
|   B|   9|   6|
|   B|   3|   8|
|   B|   9|   8|
|   C|   3|   4|
|   C|   5|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

**Step 2:** Creating another column having the `mean`, by grouping over column `A`.

```
w = Window().partitionBy('col1')
df = df.withColumn('new_col',avg(col('col2')).over(w))
df.show()
+----+----+----+-------+
|col1|col2|col3|new_col|
+----+----+----+-------+
|   B|   9|   6|    7.0|
|   B|   3|   8|    7.0|
|   B|   9|   8|    7.0|
|   C|   3|   4|    4.0|
|   C|   5|   1|    4.0|
|   A|   5|   6|   5.25|
|   A|   5|   8|   5.25|
|   A|   6|   3|   5.25|
|   A|   5|   9|   5.25|
+----+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I got the following error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm' after "w = Window().partitionBy('col1')"

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40297403/pyspark-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-jvm

Comment: I am pretty new. How do you import sqlContext. could you please mention all the packages you have imported?

Comment: My dataframe is imported from a csv file. Can it be the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: I am using `https://community.cloud.databricks.com` and I get my `sqlContext` from the website. Please search in `stackoverflow` this - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm windows()`. There are many links which may address your issue. Since, I can't reproduce this error, I don't know where exactly the fault is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of trying, I could answer the question myself. I post the answer here for anyone else with the similar question. The original file is a csv file here.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
#reading the file
df = spark.read.csv('file's name.csv', header=True)
df.show()
```

output

```
+-----+------+-----+        
|col1 | col2 | col3| 
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  6  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   6  |  3  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|A    |   5  |  9  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   9  |  6  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   3  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|B    |   9  |  8  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|C    |  3   |  4  |
+-----+------+-----+        
|C    |  5   |  1  |
+-----+------+-----+        


from pyspark.sql import functions as func
#Grouping the dataframe based on col1
col1group = df.groupBy('col1')
#Computing the average of col2 based on the grouping on col1
a= col1group.agg(func.avg("col2"))
a.show()
```

output

```
+-----+----------+
|col1 | avg(col2)|
+-----+----------+
| A   |   5.25   |
+-----+----------+
| B   |   7.0    |
+-----+----------+
| C   |   4.0    |
+-----+----------+
```

Now, we join the last table with the initial dataframe to generate our desired dataframe:

```
df=test1.join(a, on = 'lable', how = 'inner')
df.show()
```

output

```
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |col1 | col2 | col3 |avg(col2)|
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  A  |   5  |  6   | 5.25    |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  A  |   5  |  8   | 5.25    |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  A  |   6  |  3   | 5.25    |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  A  |   5  |  9   | 5.25    |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  B  |   9  |  6   | 7       |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  B  |   3  |  8   | 7       |
   +-----+------+------+---------+    
   |  B  |   9  |  8   | 7       |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  C  |   3  |  4   | 4       |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
   |  C  |   5  |  1   | 4       |
   +-----+------+------+---------+
```

Now change the name of the last column to whatever we want

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed('avg(val1)', 'new_col')
df.show()
```

output

```
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |col1 | col2 | col3 | new_col|
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  6   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  8   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   6  |  3   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  A  |   5  |  9   | 5.25   |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  B  |   9  |  6   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  B  |   3  |  8   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+    
   |  B  |   9  |  8   | 7      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  C  |   3  |  4   | 4      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
   |  C  |   5  |  1   | 4      |
   +-----+------+------+--------+
```