# Falling to import max/min/avg/col from pyspark.sql.functions

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the line in pycharm `from pyspark.sql.functions import max, min, col`.

However, it doesn't recognize those functions, even though it does recognise `log`- functions from `sql.functions`. Why don't `max`, `min` and `col` get recognised?

My pyspark version is 2.2 and my python version is 3.6 (through anaconda).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find col function in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163106/cannot-find-col-function-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't recognize them because python has it's own `max, min` functions or you've imported a package with these functions so there is a conflict. Try using an `alias` when importing the package:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
psf.max("my_col")
```