# How do I read a text file & apply a schema with PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

.txt file looks like this:

```
1234567813572468
1234567813572468
1234567813572468
1234567813572468
1234567813572468
```

When I  read it in, and sort into 3 distinct columns, I return this (perfect):

```py
df = spark.read.option("header"     , "false")\
               .option("inferSchema", "true" )\
               .text( "fixed-width-2.txt"    )

sorted_df = df.select(
    df.value.substr(1, 4).alias('col1'),
    df.value.substr(5, 4).alias('col2'),
    df.value.substr(8, 4).alias('col3'),
).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1234|5678|8135|
|1234|5678|8135|
|1234|5678|8135|
|1234|5678|8135|
|1234|5678|8135|
|1234|5678|8135|
```

However, if I were to read it again, and apply a schema...

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col3', IntegerType(), True)])
df_new = spark.read.csv("fixed-width-2.txt", schema=schema)
df_new.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
```

The data from the file is gone:

```py
df_new.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
+----+----+----+
```

So my question is, how can I read in this text file and apply a schema?

Comment: You can apply new schema to previous dataframe `df_new = spark.createDataFrame(sorted_df.rdd, schema)`. You can't use `spark.read.csv` on your data without delimiter.

Comment: I had considered that, however it returns:
# IntegerType can not accept object '1234' in type <class 'str'>

I'm going to try the approach below as well, and report back here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When reading with schema for **`col1`** as `int` this value exceeds `1234567813572468` max int value. instead read with **`LongType`**.

```
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', LongType(), True)])
spark.read.csv("path",schema=schema).show()
#+----------------+
#|            col1|
#+----------------+
#|1234567813572468|
#|1234567813572468|
#|1234567813572468|
#|1234567813572468|
#|1234567813572468|
#+----------------+
```

**`Using RDD Api:`**

Easier way would be read the fixed width file using `.textFile`(results an rdd) then apply transformations using `.map` then convert to **dataframe** using the schema.

---

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col3', IntegerType(), True)])
df=spark.createDataFrame(
spark.sparkContext.textFile("fixed_width.csv").\
map(lambda x:(int(x[0:4]),int(x[4:8]),int(x[8:12]))),schema)

df.show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|1234|5678|1357|
#|1234|5678|1357|
#|1234|5678|1357|
#|1234|5678|1357|
#|1234|5678|1357|
#+----+----+----+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col2: integer (nullable = true)
# |-- col3: integer (nullable = true)
```

---

**`Using DataFrame Api:`**

```
df = spark.read.option("header"     , "false")\
               .option("inferSchema", "true" )\
               .text( "path")

sorted_df = df.select(
    df.value.substr(1, 4).alias('col1'),
    df.value.substr(5, 4).alias('col2'),
    df.value.substr(8, 4).alias('col3'),
)
#dynamic cast expression
casting=[(col(col_name).cast("int")).name(col_name) for col_name in sorted_df.columns]
sorted_df=sorted_df.select(casting)

#required dataframe
sorted_df.show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#+----+----+----+

#just in case if you want to change the types
schema = StructType([StructField('col1', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col2', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('col3', IntegerType(), True)])

df=spark.createDataFrame(sorted_df.rdd,schema)
df.show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#|1234|5678|8135|
#+----+----+----+
```

Comment: This is --exactly-- what I was looking for! Thank you for being so thorough as well, and providing a second approach, as it helped me understand multiple ways to solve this.

For others, I am running in a Jupyter notebook, and saw that 'col' was not found in PySpark, as used in the example above. To resolve that, I used this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163106/cannot-find-col-function-in-pyspark/40163314