# Explode array values into multiple columns using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I want to explode array values in such a way that each value gets assigned to a new column. I tried using explode but I couldn't get the desired output. Below is my output

[image: output in hand]

[image: Schema:]

[image: Required output:]

this is the code

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
if __name__ == "__main__":
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[3]") \
    .appName("DataOps") \
    .getOrCreate()

dataFrameJSON = spark.read \
    .option("multiLine", True) \
    .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") \
    .json("data.json")

dataFrameJSON.printSchema()
sub_DF = dataFrameJSON.select(explode("values.line").alias("new_values"))
sub_DF.printSchema()

sub_DF2 = sub_DF.select("new_values.*")
sub_DF2.printSchema()
sub_DF.show(truncate=False)

new_DF = sub_DF2.select("id", "period.*", "property")
new_DF.show(truncate=False)
new_DF.printSchema()
```

this is data:

```
{
        "values" : {
            "line" : [
                {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "period" : {
                        "start_ts" : "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "end_ts" : "2020-01-01T00:15:00"
                    },
                    "property" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "PID",
                            "val" : "P120E12345678"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "EngID",
                            "val" : "PANELID00000000"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "TownIstat",
                            "val" : "12058091"
                        },
                        {
                            "name" : "ActiveEng",
                            "val" : "5678.1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
}
```

Comment: Please put code examples, error outputs in text instead of images so it is easier for the community to help you.

Comment: @ Mikayel Saghyan, I hope now the code and sample data are visible to you? I am trying to produce the required output as given in above link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you include the data instead of screenshots ?

Meanwhile, assuming that `df` is the dataframe being used, what we need to do, is to create a new dataframe, while exrtracting the `vals` from the previous `property` array to new columns, and droping the `property` column at last :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
output_df = df.withColumn("PID", col("property")[0].val).withColumn("EngID", col("property")[1].val).withColumn("TownIstat", col("property")[2].val).withColumn("ActiveEng", col("property")[3].val).drop("property")
```

In case the `element`was of type `ArrayType` use the following :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
output_df = df.withColumn("PID", col("property")[0][1]).withColumn("EngID", col("property")[1][1]).withColumn("TownIstat", col("property")[2][1]).withColumn("ActiveEng", col("property")[3][1]).drop("property")
```

Explode will explode the arrays into new Rows, not columns, see this : [pyspark explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=explode#module-pyspark.sql.functions)

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried your suggested code, but I am getting the following error: TypeError: col() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'

Comment: Could you include your code in the question above ? with data samples ?
When you edit, try to edit your own question, not my answer, you're on the right path

Comment: code and sample data is available now, please help me to produce the required output as I have provided in the screenshot, thank you in advance

Comment: You probably forgot to insert the "property" string inside of col(), can you show all of your code after using my answer ? I just used the same code on Databricks, and it works just fine, no errors

Comment: sub_DF = dataFrameJSON.select("UrbanDataset.values.line")
sub_DF2 = dataFrameJSON.select(explode("UrbanDataset.values.line").alias("new_values"))
    sub_DF3 = sub_DF2.select("new_values.*")

    new_DF = sub_DF3.select("id", "period.*", "property")
    new_DF.show(truncate=False)

    output_df = new_DF.withColumn("PID", col("property")[0][1]) \
        .withColumn("EngID", col("property")[1][1]) \
        .withColumn("TownIstat", col("property")[2][1]) \
        .withColumn("ActiveEng", col("property")[3][1]).drop("property")
    output_df.show(truncate=False)

Comment: How I can show the code in a readable format? I am sorry, I am new to this forum

Comment: could you please share your complete code?, including all the imports?, I think I have a problem with col package

Comment: Now, I am getting the following error:   pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it's 1;  could you please look into the issue?

Comment: You should use the .val notation, because your schema is a struct, not an array.
So, use the first code snippet not the second

Comment: Perfect, don't forget to accept and upvote the good answer
A best practice, is to use your own schema instead of inferred schema, try it.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a general solution and works even when the JSONs are messy** (different ordering of elements or if some of the elements are missing)

You got to **flatten** first, `regexp_replace` to **split** the 'property' column and finally **pivot**. This also avoids hard coding of the new column names.

Constructing your dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()), StructField("start_ts", StringType()), StructField("end_ts", StringType()), \
    StructField("property", ArrayType(StructType(  [StructField("name", StringType()),  StructField("val", StringType())]    )))])

data = [[1, "2010", "2020", [["PID", "P123"], ["Eng", "PA111"], ["Town", "999"], ["Act", "123.1"]]],\
         [2, "2011", "2012", [["PID", "P456"], ["Eng", "PA222"], ["Town", "777"], ["Act", "234.1"]]]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)
+---+--------+------+------------------------------------------------------+    
|id |start_ts|end_ts|property                                              |
+---+--------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |2010    |2020  |[[PID, P123], [Eng, PA111], [Town, 999], [Act, 123.1]]|
|2  |2011    |2012  |[[PID, P456], [Eng, PA222], [Town, 777], [Act, 234.1]]|
+---+--------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Flattening and pivoting:

```
df_flatten = df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0],x[1], x[2], y) for y in x[3]]).toDF(['id', 'start_ts', 'end_ts', 'property'])\
            .select('id', 'start_ts', 'end_ts', col("property").cast("string"))

df_split = df_flatten.select('id', 'start_ts', 'end_ts', regexp_replace(df_flatten.property, "[\[\]]", "").alias("replacced_col"))\
                .withColumn("arr", split(col("replacced_col"), ", "))\
                .select(col("arr")[0].alias("col1"), col("arr")[1].alias("col2"), 'id', 'start_ts', 'end_ts')

final_df = df_split.groupby(df_split.id,)\
                        .pivot("col1")\
                        .agg(first("col2"))\
                        .join(df,'id').drop("property")
```

Output:

```
final_df.show()
+---+-----+-----+----+----+--------+------+
| id|  Act|  Eng| PID|Town|start_ts|end_ts|
+---+-----+-----+----+----+--------+------+
|  1|123.1|PA111|P123| 999|    2010|  2020|
|  2|234.1|PA222|P456| 777|    2011|  2012|
+---+-----+-----+----+----+--------+------+
```

Comment: many thanks for your response,  by using your code I am getting the following error: TypeError: col() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg',    I think I have an issue with col package? can you please share you complete code including all the imports? thank you

Comment: i have added the imports. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: from pyspark.sql.functions import col,
cannot find reference 'col' in 'functions.py'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163106/cannot-find-col-function-in-pyspark/

Comment: ample of thanks for your response, it's working now for me as well

Comment: Why all the hassle instead of simply extracting the relevant data by accessing it, then create the new columns ? I don't get it, this is complicating things.

Comment: It's because this is a general solution. I understand that it is simpler to just use indices for this question. But if the **order** of the elements in 'property' is changed or if one of them is **missing**, the indices method wouldn't work. I'm factoring in these cases of **messy JSONs** in my solution. (And no hard-coding of column names. Works for 'n' number of elements)

Comment: @Cena I have the exact same requirement as well, just that I have to do it in Scala instead of Python. What do I have to change in your code above to get the `flatmap`s to work?