# How do I create columns named with values in a list and assign values from an array?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

input_list=[inputA,inputB,inputC]

I have a table like this below

```
job_id | timestamp                          | input_values      |
|:----   |:---------------------------------- | ------------------|                     
| job1   | 2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000       | [0.12,0.34,0.23]  |
| job2   | 2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000       | [0.23,0.55,0.12]  |
| job3   | 2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000       | [0.23,0.12,0.32]  |
```

and I want to conver it to a table like this

```
 job_id | timestamp                      | input_values      |inputA|inputB|inputC|
|:----   |:------------------------------| ------------------|------|------|------|                    
| job1   | 2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000  | [0.12,0.34,0.23]  |0.12  |0.34  |0.23  |
| job2   | 2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000  | [0.23,0.55,0.12]  |0.23  |0.55  |0.12  |
| job3   | 2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000  | [0.23,0.12,0.32]  |0.23  |0.12  |0.32  |
```

How can I do this using Pyspark? Thank you! Also needs a performance tuning as well as this table is so large.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explode array values into multiple columns using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082921/explode-array-values-into-multiple-columns-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A bit more generic solution***

**Input DataFrame**

```
data = [("job1", "2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000", [0.12,0.34,0.23]),
        ("job2", "2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000", [0.23,0.55,0.12]),
        ("job3", "2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000", [0.23,0.12,0.32])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["job_id", "timestamp", "input_values"])
df.show(truncate=False)

+------+----------------------------+------------------+
|job_id|timestamp                   |input_values      |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+
|job1  |2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000|[0.12, 0.34, 0.23]|
|job2  |2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.55, 0.12]|
|job3  |2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.12, 0.32]|
+------+----------------------------+------------------+
```

Create a dictionary with the values from the `input_values` column, we can use the `collect_list()` function to create an array of all the `input_values`, and then convert that array to a dictionary using `create_map()`. 
Once the dictionary is created, we can create new columns based upon the ones in `input_values` list within `input_values_dict`.

See the below implementation for details -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import string

input_values_dict = df.select(create_map(lit("input_values"), collect_list("input_values")).alias("dict")).collect()[0]["dict"]

# type(input_values_dict)
# print(input_values_dict)

# Create new columns for each element in input_values list
num_cols = len(input_values_dict['input_values'][0])

for i in range(num_cols):
    col_name = f"input{string.ascii_uppercase[i]}"
    df = df.withColumn(col_name, col('input_values')[i])

df.show(truncate=False)

+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job_id|timestamp                   |input_values      |inputA|inputB|inputC|
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job1  |2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000|[0.12, 0.34, 0.23]|0.12  |0.34  |0.23  |
|job2  |2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.55, 0.12]|0.23  |0.55  |0.12  |
|job3  |2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.12, 0.32]|0.23  |0.12  |0.32  |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution .

```
import string
data = [("job1", "2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000", [0.12,0.34,0.23]),
        ("job2", "2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000", [0.23,0.55,0.12]),
        ("job3", "2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000", [0.23,0.12,0.32])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["job_id", "timestamp", "input_values"])
df.show(truncate=False)


df.select("job_id", "timestamp", "input_values",
          *[F.col("input_values")[i].alias("input{}".format(string.ascii_uppercase[i])) for i in range(3)])\
.show(10,0)

+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job_id|timestamp                   |input_values      |inputA|inputB|inputC|
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+
|job1  |2023-03-01T19:12:00.000+0000|[0.12, 0.34, 0.23]|0.12  |0.34  |0.23  |
|job2  |2023-03-01T19:13:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.55, 0.12]|0.23  |0.55  |0.12  |
|job3  |2023-03-01T19:14:00.000+0000|[0.23, 0.12, 0.32]|0.23  |0.12  |0.32  |
+------+----------------------------+------------------+------+------+------+

kindly upvote if you like my solution
```