# PySpark 3.1.2 - where are functions such as day, date, month

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, built-in

Spark document [Built-in Functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#day) has function such as `day`, `date`, `month`.

However, they are not available in PySpark. Why is this?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    day,
    date,
    month
)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [162], in <module>
----> 1 from pyspark.sql.functions import (
      2     day,
      3     date,
      4     month
      5 )

ImportError: cannot import name 'day' from 'pyspark.sql.functions' (/opt/spark/spark-3.1.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py)
```

```
$ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_312
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2021-05-24T04:27:48Z
Revision de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

Comment: This post seems to have some likely explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163106/cannot-find-col-function-in-pyspark

Comment: Not all functions in Spark SQL are available in DataFrame API.  But for these three functions you mention, you have `dayofmonth` == `day`, `month` and `to_date` (without fmt) == `date`. See [pyspark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#functions)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `day` with `dayofmonth`, `date` with `to_date`, `month` stays similiar.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dayofmonth, to_date, month, col

dateDF = spark.createDataFrame([("06-03-2009"),("07-24-2009")],"string")
dateDF.select(
    col("value"),
    to_date(col("value"),"MM-dd-yyyy")).show()

+----------+--------------------------+
|     value|to_date(value, MM-dd-yyyy)|
+----------+--------------------------+
|06-03-2009|                2009-06-03|
|07-24-2009|                2009-07-24|
+----------+--------------------------+
```